# Hindi fonts are not getting displayed in browser?

Tags: servlets

I am using UTF-8 encoding to display hindi fonts in servlet but hindi fonts are displaying in following format -

```
à¤¶à¤ªà¤¥ à¤à¤¯ à¤à¤° à
```

I am using following code-

```
response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        t.merge(context, writer);

        String s = writer.toString();
```

in servlet

```
response.getCharacterEncoding() // it is showing ISO-8859-1 by default
```

and i have set both character encoding UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1 in both jsp and servlet  but problem was not resolved.

One thing is more, i am using mozila firefox and in it character encoding is Unicode. is there any effect on our output because of mozila's character encoding.

Please help me?

Comment: Well u can use this library http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/

Comment: what about in you jsp page? have you set encoding to utf8?

Comment: i have tried to use commons-lang but still having problem.

Comment: yes i have set utf-8 encoding in jsp.

Comment: ohh then what is string that is u getting that is in hindi is it?

Comment: i am fetching hindi contents from velocity template(.vm file) and using string writer i am converting fetched contents into string.

Comment: Do one thing then. try to convert that into the English first and then  convert it to hindi na